# Changing target in form of Asp.net page

Tags: asp.net

I am using IFrame in my ASP.NET pages.  For the page that I am referencing in my IFrame, I have a gridview (I also have CommandField that referencing another asp.net page) and paging enabled.

I wanted to display a new page (outside of Iframe) when a user clicks on the commandfield in the gridview.  In order to do that I set form's target to "_parent".  This works fine (it open a new page outside of Iframe).  Now, my problem is that when i click on the paging to go to next page in the gridview, it also opens the gridview outside of IFrame (which I dont want to happen).  I want it to open within the Iframe.

Is there any way I could set the target as I needed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use some jQuery: (Just threw this idea together, not tested)

```
$("#myElement").click(function() {

   if(window.location != window.parent.location)
   {
      // window is in iframe
      $(this).attr("target", "_self");
   }else{
      $(this).attr("target", "_parent");
   }     
});
```